# ld linker is adding extra assembly instruction when outputing to binary file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, nasm, ld

I have a C source file which contains only one function which does nothing but returns a value to a function, I have generated an object file from it by using gcc -ffreestanding options to output an object file without standard library and entry point but when I try to use the gnu linker to output a binary file it adds extra assembly instruction to it the below is the source file

```
int test_function() {
    return 0x4141;
}
```

I used this gcc command to generate an object file **gcc -ffreestanding -c source.c -o source.o**

I used this command for ld linker
**ld -o source.bin -Ttext 0x0 --oformat binary source.o**

the result I got after using the linker is

dumped using **ndisasm -b 32 source.bin**

```
00000000  F30F1EFA          rep hint_nop55 edx
00000004  55                push ebp
00000005  48                dec eax
00000006  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000008  B8BABA0000        mov eax,0xbaba
0000000D  5D                pop ebp
0000000E  C3                ret
0000000F  0000              add [eax],al
00000011  0000              add [eax],al
00000013  0000              add [eax],al
00000015  0000              add [eax],al
00000017  0000              add [eax],al
00000019  0000              add [eax],al
0000001B  0000              add [eax],al
0000001D  0000              add [eax],al
0000001F  0000              add [eax],al
00000021  0000              add [eax],al
00000023  0000              add [eax],al
00000025  0000              add [eax],al
00000027  0000              add [eax],al
00000029  0000              add [eax],al
0000002B  0000              add [eax],al
0000002D  0000              add [eax],al
0000002F  0000              add [eax],al
00000031  0000              add [eax],al
00000033  0000              add [eax],al
00000035  0000              add [eax],al
00000037  0000              add [eax],al
00000039  0000              add [eax],al
0000003B  0000              add [eax],al
0000003D  0000              add [eax],al
0000003F  0000              add [eax],al
00000041  0000              add [eax],al
00000043  0000              add [eax],al
00000045  0000              add [eax],al
00000047  0000              add [eax],al
00000049  0000              add [eax],al
```

the **add [eax], al** asm instruction is added by the linker and I just don't want that, I only want the .text segment (THE FIRST 7 INSTRUCTIONS) are the C program assembly equivalent instrution the rest I don't know where it came from.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those instructions are required for alignment. Notice that the byte values are all 0.

Comment: Ohhh Yeah I see so it doesnt affect the memory?

Comment: I mean in terms of space?

Comment: The padding is _not_ executed. It goes until 0x1000 [and a bit beyond]. This is 4096 decimal, which is the size of a page. Probably alignment to start the `.data` section on a page boundary. Try adding some global data. If you do that, you'll see padding up to 0x3000 where the initialized data starts.

Comment: ummm I get it thanks a lot.